# Accessing parent window angular scope from child window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update scope value on parent window from a child popup.But whenever I try to access the parent window scope,it returns undefined. As it involves two window, I couldn't create a fiddle for this. Code sample is pasted below.

**Main page (main.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
     function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
   <div id="ctrl" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      Hello, {{name}}!
      <input type="button" value="Open popup!!" onclick="window.open('child.html');"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Child window (child.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     function change(){
      var e = window.opener.document.getElementById('ctrl');
      var ae = angular.element(e);
      var s = ae.scope();
      s.name="New Superhero";
      s.$apply();
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" value="Update parent scope!" onclick="change();"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here whenever I try to access scope from the angular element , as shown above in change method, it returns undefined [ae.scope()].But when the same code moved to a function in parent window [only difference in how 'ctrl' element is being accessed], it worked fine and I was able to update the scope variable. Can anyone point out what actually is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this will work as two windows are involved, as the child window may not have the access to the scripts\functions loaded on parent. Why dont you look at options like Angularstrap, which have a model popup http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks for suggestion.Requirement insist on using a popup.So cant go with modal window option. Also,child window will be able to access dom and script on the parent window. So I believe something else is going wrong here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `angular` reference from the opener:

```
function change() {
  var s = window.opener.angular.element('#ctrl').scope();
  s.name="New Superhero";
  s.$apply();
}
```

Comment: This will no longer work if you turn off debug info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#debugInfoEnabled. Since it is recommended to disable debug for production applications then this solution will not work.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar need and had the same problem accessing the scope using angular.element.  I was was able to solve it as follows though:

In your main/parent controller do something like this:

```
$scope.food = 'Mac & Cheese';
window.$windowScope = $scope;
$window.open('views/anotherWindow.html', '_blank','menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,personalbar=yes');
```

Then in the child window controller you can access $windowScope like this:

```
$scope.parentWindow = window.opener.$windowScope;
console.log($scope.parentWindow.food);
```

An alternative to putting data directly into the scope would be to use $window scope to [broadcast and/or emit events](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#communication-between-services-and-controllers), which is the preferred way of cross-controller communication in angular.

Comment: how do you move the scope into the child window. It says scope undefined