# AngularJS (1.5) detach panel to child window and vice versa

Tags: angularjs

I have a child controller which I can use inside some main controller. For example, it's a panel inside the main page controller. Now I need to open a child window with this child controller inside. **How can I do this**?

For example, I have a video player panel and I want it to become detachable and scalable in size.

My child controller has its own template-file and I inject it to the main controller with this:

```
...
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <span ng-include="AVTemplateUrl" ng-controller="VideoCtrl as AV" data-ng-init="AV.init()"></span>
</div>
...
```

and contructor for the child:

```
angular.module('myApp.video', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('VideoCtrl', ['$scope', ...],
    function ($scope, ...) {
        $scope.AVTemplateUrl = 'view/device/video.html';
        let AV = $scope.AV = { ... }
...
```

P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: Is this angular or angularjs related?

Comment: @jota-toledo, it's
`"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.7"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066146/2982280 and here http://embed.plnkr.co/dz1A1h/

Parent controller:

```
.controller(
    ...
    let model = $scope.model = {
        detach() {
            // remove the controller panel from dom
        },
        maximize() {
            // detach panel to a new child window
            this.detach();
            window.$windowScope = $scope; // $scope contains 'model' field
            $window.open('_child_window_url_', '_child_window_name_', 'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,status=no - window params');
        },
        onClick() {
            // some DOM handler - button click, for example
        },
        ...
    };
    ...
);
```

Child controller:

1) use router:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('_child_window_url_', {
      templateUrl: '_template_file_path_',
      controller: '_child_controller_name_'
    });
}])
```

2) implement the DOM handlers to make them call the parent's handlers:

```
onClick: function () {
    window.opener.$windowScope.model.onClick();
},
```